# How to find google play developer registration id?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to move an app to a new developer account with these instructions:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en

The step 3 is confusing. I can't seem to find the registration id anywhere.

Can someone help me find the registration id?

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the link you provided, check the email which you registered your account with and in the registration email should be the transaction ID. If you can't find it there you need to enter [payments.google.com](https://payments.google.com/) with that account and in each transaction you'll find the transaction ID.

Answer (score 0):

go to [here](https://payments.google.com/payments/home)

select activity

in the transaction id copy  at the start of "Registration" to latest part

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna know what is your **Google Paid Id** use this link:

https://pay.google.com/payments/home?bcn

in the menu button you can see the details about the paid id of each account that you have.